# ImportError cannot import name Deque with spacy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, spacy

I'm trying to import spacy to use on VSCode, but I am getting an error: "Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name Deque."

I did pip install -U spacy in my virtual environment. Wondering how to solve the error so that I can use spacy? This import error goes away if I try other Python libraries. For ex, "import nltk" works fine.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What is the python version that you are using?

Comment: python3.9. I created the venv using python3.9 -m venv env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you reinstall the module "spacy" in the currently selected Python environment (the python environment shown in the lower left corner of VS Code). You could use the command "`pip show spacy`"(or `pip3 show spacy`) to check the installation location of the module:

[image]

Debug:

[image]

If it still doesn't work, please try to reinstall the python extension and reload VS Code.